# can't seem to disable a button based on a condition

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to disable the equal button on my calculator when user pressed it without any inputs and throw a warning. The reason I am trying to disable my equal button without an input is because it returns "undefined" on the screen, I don't want it.

```
 equalsKey.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if(display.innerHTML.length < 0) { 
    equalsKey.disabled = false; 
} else { 
  equalsKey.disabled = true;
  alert("Clear the calculator and input numbers");  
}  
displayResult(); 
  
});
```

This is what I tried to accomplish it, it does disables the equal button and throws a warning but it throws the warning when the user inserted an input and made normal calculations. I want my calculator to stop throwing me the error

> alert("Clear the calculator and input numbers");

when there is an input in the display, nevertheless, it still throws the error.

Is there anyway to tackle this? I am open to any possible ways to accomplish this, this has been my approach.

https://codepen.io/furkancodes-the-typescripter/pen/jOyGJvx
HERE is the Code.

Thanks.

Comment: What if length is not less than 0, but actually 0? Your statement should be `display.length != 0`

Comment: `if(!display.length < 0)` — That’s not part of your CodePen. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. When is a length _less than_ 0? In other words, at what point is the length of a string _negative_?

Comment: So the first test is to see if the length of the display is 0 or greater?

Comment: I edited the codepen and the question. I stated my desired result as well as the result I am getting too.

Comment: @Nordii yes and according to that value, it disables the equal button so the user cannot take any further actions. I also added clearBtn.click in there to clear the display and reactivate the button as well, but it throws an error when there is an input too which I want to eliminate

Comment: Please explain what a string with negative length looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use your actual variables instead of html text:

```
equalsKey.addEventListener("click", function () {

    if (displayVal === "" && firstNumber === "") {
        equalsKey.disabled = true;
        display.textContent = 0;
        alert("Clear the calculator and input numbers");
    }else{
        equalsKey.disabled = false;
        displayResult(); 
    }
});
```

Edit: Okay, i played with your calculator a bit further. So, to make it work as expected you can

replace "equals" listener with:

```
equalsKey.addEventListener("click", function () {

    if (displayVal !== "" && firstNumber !== "" && clickedOperator !== "") {
        //equalsKey.disabled = false;
        displayResult();
    }else{
        //equalsKey.disabled = true;
        clearBtn.click();
        display.textContent = 0;
        alert("Invalid operation. Please try again");
    }
});
```

Then remove this line from method displayResult(){} :

```
display.textContent = firstNumber + displayVal; // <--
```

Finally remove class "operator" from equals button in html, so that we can process it separately.